# create template for a structure with a variable number of entries - matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

Is there an easy way to create a structure such as:

```
>> s
    'nb1': []
    'nb2': []
    'nb3': []
    'nb4': []
    'nb5': []
    'nb6': []
    'nb7': []
    'nb8': []
    'nb9': []
    'nb10': []
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to change the amount of entries. So if I wanted 400 entries:

```
>> s
    'nb1': []
    'nb2': []
       ...
    'nb400': []
```

Comment: so did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
clc
clear

N = 10;
s(N).Value = []; % Set the last value to [], so that all the rest is also initialized to []. Pre-allocation can significantly speed up the code in many cases.

for k = 1:N
s(k).Name = sprintf('nb%i',k)
end
```

I can't test it right know but hopefully this is what you're looking for.